# How to Render List as Json in play framework 1.2.x

Tags: json, playframework

I am trying to `render` a list as `json` in `play framework 1.2.x`. As I search from net, I found `Gosn` was used. but it didn't help me anyway. I need to render any `object list` as `json` in my `controller action`. Here is my code and error trace.

```
@Entity(name="country")
public class Country extends Model{
    public String name;
    public String code;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy="country", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     public List<City> cities;
}

@Entity
public class City extends Model{
    public String name;
    public String code;
    @ManyToOne
    public Country country;
}


public static void ajaxGetCities(long countryid){
    List<City> cities = City.find("byCountry_id", countryid).fetch();
    renderJSON(cities);
}


at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:879)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:879)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:879)
```

Comment: I didn't see the type of exception in your stacktrace. Though I suspect it is a circular reference problem. Do you have object reference loop in your `City` object? For example, City has a object A reference and object A also has object reference in it.

Comment: I have updated my question by adding country and city classes.

Comment: Try to set fetch = FetchType.LAZY on cities in Country class.

Comment: I tried that, but it is not working. same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a circular reference problem. When gson tries to serialize City object (say, City A) in list, it finds Country object so it tries to serialize Country object too. However, there are many City object references in Country object and one of these references points to City A. So there is a reference loop here.

There are two options to resolve circular reference in your case:

A. Remove reference of City object in Country object.

```java
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="country", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<City> cities;
```

`OneToMany` is kind of redundant to me since I could always find cities of the Country by a static method in City Object.

B. Keep `cities` fields and implement `CountrySerializer` to prevent circular reference in gson.

```java
    public class CountrySerializer implements JsonSerializer<Country> {

        public JsonElement serialize(User src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setExclusionStrategies(new LocalExclusionStrategy()).create();
            return gson.toJsonTree(src);
        }   

        public static class LocalExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                return false;
            }   

            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                // add exlusion rules here:
                // exclude field whose name is "cities"
                return f.getName().toLowerCase().equals("cities");
            }   
        }   
    }
```

to use it:

```
    public static void ajaxGetCities(long countryid){
        List<City> cities = City.find("byCountry_id", countryid).fetch();
        renderJSON(cities, new CountrySerializer());
    }
```

if you have complicated structure in return object, you could have multiple serializer in use at the same time.

```
    renderJSON(cities, new CountrySerializer(), new CodeSerializer());
```